# Javascript overlay function

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to do the overlay function.

```js
function toggleOverlay(){
 var overlay = document.getElementById('overlay');
 var specialBox = document.getElementById('specialBox');
 overlay.style.opacity = .8;
 if(overlay.style.display == "block"){
  overlay.style.display = "none";
  specialBox.style.display = "none";
 } else {
  overlay.style.display = "block";
  specialBox.style.display = "block";
 }
}
```

```css
div#overlay {
 display: none;
 z-index: 2;
 background: #000;
 position: fixed;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 top: 0px;
 left: 0px;
 text-align: center;
}
div#specialBox {
 display: none;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 3;
 margin: 150px auto 0px auto;
 width: 500px; 
 height: 300px;
 background: #FFF;
 color: #000;
}
div#wrapper {
 position:absolute;
 top: 0px;
 left: 0px;
 padding-left:24px;
}
```

```html
<div id="overlay"></div>

<div id="specialBox">
  <p>Special box content ...</p> 
  <button onmousedown="toggleOverlay()">Close Overlay</button>
</div>

<div id="wrapper">
 
  <button onmousedown="toggleOverlay()">Apply Overlay</button>
</div>
```

In the current function, when i click the `Apply overlay` button the pop up is coming. But as per my requirement the pop up has to come when i execute the script i.e. without invoking the `apply overlay` button.

Please suggest me on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Invoke the function whenever you need it...

Comment: First you need to move your script block after body tag. i.e. after rendering html, you need to call javascript code. and then simply call your function.

Answer (score 3):

Add this to your javascript AFTER the function

```
window.onload = function(){ 
  toggleOverlay()
}
```

This invokes the functions when the page is loaded

Answer (score 0):

Alternate option can be use `self-invokling function`

```
var publicObj = {}; 
(
  publicObj.toggle = function togglefunction() {
    var overlay = document.getElementById('overlay');
    var specialBox = document.getElementById('specialBox');
    overlay.style.opacity = .8;
    if (overlay.style.display == "block") {
      overlay.style.display = "none";
      specialBox.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      overlay.style.display = "block";
      specialBox.style.display = "block";
    }
  })(publicObj);

function toggleOverlay(){
  publicObj.toggle();
}
```

[Fiddle](https://output.jsbin.com/soruvoyipu)